# Why is SQL Server Report Server 2005 / 2008 hardcoded to http://?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I use a Apache server as frontend balancer. So I also pass requests to a SQL Server Report Server.
The main URL is SSL secured, so the ProxyPass through the RS works with basic auth.

The report server has a interesting issue. Most of the links in the report server seems to be hardcoded http://. With that issue, many links you click on the /reports URL gives you a "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)" from the Apache front end server.

You can browse reports, you can open them, but if you click e.g. the root link on top or the view details link to switch the list mode, then the report server uses http://yourserver/reports/... which results in an error. Correct links are https:// in this setup.

Link which are not http:// hardcoded works so far.

I opened a support ticket at Microsoft already which escalated to redmond to the dev team. The result was... this is by design and can't be changed. Is MS really so *censored*? Anyway. Did anyone face the same situation and got a workaround to fix that?

I am not that familiar with Apache config, but maybe is there a way to do a URL rewrite within the Apache? So if the Apache gets an `http://myfrontendurl/reports/...` it replaces the request with `https://` ?

Comment: I have the same behavior.  I really hate when they claim ridiculous things are by design.  Arrgh.

Comment: Perhaps you can disable the http bindings in reporting services and it will no longer switch between the two.

Comment: Hey sam, can you explain in detail what you mean? I tried in the rsreportserver.config to define a main URL with https:// with no result.

Comment: I'm referring to the reportserver configuration panel, accessed from the sql server config start menu area.  Connect to the servername and you'll be able to poke around a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend deactivating the http access from the Reporting Services Configuration tool  and seeing what happens.

Comment: In fact you crash the /report server if you start setup SSL cert and then define a specific IP address :S

Comment: I didn't manage to setup it like this and the server is a backend server, so it shouldnt have a SSL cert. So I will concentrate now for a solution that rewrite all URL's with the apache... second way is to kick the /reports and read the catalog table to make my own user interface...

Comment: Accepted this as answer due the fact the comments helped me out.

Comment: Funny you close this out.  I've just been struggling with an SSRS install for the past month or two.  This URL is applicable, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281307.aspx - even though it is labeled 2012 it has all the proper instructions they leave out for 2008 (registry mods).

Comment: Even more funny is that I ran through the same document of the link you posted :)